# Stylizing images / style transfer between images

Tags: windows, gratis, offline

It seems like the technology of stylizing images is quite mature now. Websites like [this](https://reiinakano.com/arbitrary-image-stylization-tfjs/) take two images as input, one image for the contents that you want to be shown and one image that defines the style. I would like to benefit from such an AI-based image manipulation in an offline way.

Requirements:

- The size of the content image shall not be limited.
- The size of the style needn't necessarily match the size of the content.
- The output resolution shall support 1920x1920, so that I can create FullHD images in portrait or landscape mode.
- works on Windows (currently I have Win10)